# SAP GUI script for information window

Tags: sap-gui

I need to get this window to click on the continue button if it pops out when no data is changed and continue with the next cell [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use something like this...

**Note:** you need to change this **"wnd[1]/usr/tblSAPLV14ATCTRL_D0102"** with the script you recorded.

```
If Not session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tblSAPLV14ATCTRL_D0102", False) Is Nothing Then

session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[24]").press

End If
```